# Creating views programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios

I set views programmatically. Here is how I do that. Let's say I have SettingsViewController.m

In this file I have two methods

```
-(void)loadView
{
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];

    self.view = view;
    [view release];
}

-(void)didViewLoad
{
//  In that method I create some buttons labels etc
}
```

Is my approach correct ? To create the view in loadView method and buttons, labels etc in viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest it doesn't *really* matter if you put the code for creating views in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView`. `viewDidLoad` is called after the view is loaded, so will even be called if you are instantiating from a XIB. So that's a good place to add extra views if you're using a XIB. If you're programatically creating the view like you are in `loadView` then you can put the creation of your buttons, labels, etc in `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` and it won't really make a difference - `viewDidLoad` is pretty much called straight after `loadView` runs anyway.

Personally if I'm creating a view programatically using `loadView` then I will put all of the view creation code in there rather than in `viewDidLoad`.